# Enumerate single item without label but aligned with other labels

Tags: enumerate, labels, enumitem, alignment

I use `enumerate` to create a second minimalistic TOC. The unnumbered chapters should be aligned with normal chapters.

[image: Undesired alignment of Introduction]

So the unnumbered chapter Introduction should be aligned with the 1 from chapter Main Body and not with the text "Main Body".

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
10pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\spacing{1.5}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

List of the chapters, sections, items and sub-items.\\

\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*]
    \item[] Introduction
    \item Main Body
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
        \item Main Body Section
        \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
            \item Main Body Subsection
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that the list numbering is right-aligned by default, as can be seen in this example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \setcounter{enumi}{9}%
  \item Tenth
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
  \item First
  \setcounter{enumi}{9}%
  \item Tenth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This is so that large lists can still maintain an appropriate horizontal alignment if they have large (wide) labels. This alignment can be changed within [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) with the `align` key-value. This is important because it is otherwise difficult to align an unenumerated item with the number of an enumerated one on-the-fly. Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

List of the chapters, sections, items and sub-items.

% Align outer enumeration numbering to left and reduce width of label to 1em
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*,align=left,labelwidth=1em]
  \item[] \hspace*{\dimexpr-\labelsep-\labelwidth}Introduction
  \item Main Body
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
    \item Main Body Section
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
      \item Main Body Subsection
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate} 

% Retain original labelling alignment and fake label width
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*]
  \item[] \hspace*{-\labelsep}\llap{I}ntroduction
  \item Main Body
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
    \item Main Body Section
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
      \item Main Body Subsection
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

If you really want the alignment to be perfect in the second case, then you can calculate the width of the label and use that instead of `\llap`:

```
% Retain original labelling alignment and actual label width
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*]
  \makeatletter
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{1}% Capture width of next label
  \item[] \hspace*{\dimexpr-\labelsep-\@tempdima}Introduction
  \makeatother
  \item Main Body
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
    \item Main Body Section
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
      \item Main Body Subsection
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

The value of the *next* item can also be calculated rather than using a fixed value:

```
\settowidth{\@tempdima}{\number\numexpr\value{enumi}+1}% Width of next item label
```

Comment: @ Werner Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For what you like to obtain is probably better to use `minitoc` or similar package, however with `enumerate` you can try the following solution:

**Edit 1:**
with added global settings for items idents:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\spacing{1.5}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

List of the chapters, sections, items and sub-items.


\vspace{\baselineskip} % <---added
Introduction   % <--- moved out of list
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*]   % <--- added leftmargin=*
    \item Main Body
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
        \item Main Body Section
        \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
            \item Main Body Subsection
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 2 & 3:**
After second comment of OP I guess, that he like to have something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\spacing{1.5}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label*=\arabic*, leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2,3]{label*=.\arabic*, leftmargin=*}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
List of the chapters, sections, items and sub-items.

\vspace{\baselineskip} % <---added

\hspace*{1em}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em} % moved list to the right
Introduction   % <--- moved out of list
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Main Body
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Main Body Section
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Main Body Subsection
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Is there a way to add the global indent again via maybe a local parident? I couldn't find the length that holds the default indent.

Comment: @DanielStich, see edited answer.

Comment: I still  get the same output that your pictures shows. I'd like to indent all items including Introduction.

Comment: @DanielStich, you should write your question more clear ...  Now I need to guess, what you mean. I'm not sure if if I guessed what you want.

Comment: Alright, basically exactly what I was looking for. I've compared the list from my MWE and yours. It seems like I have to adjust the indent of the minipage manually (5.7mm looks good). But is there a specific length that describes the distance between left margin and enumerate labels?

Comment: @DanielStich, sorry, but i not understand (i.e. I'm lost in your demands) what you like to have. Please read documentation for `enumitem`.  In it are described all options which package offer. If you have new problem, please ask new question where clearly stated, what is the problem, which you like to solve.